# PHP associative array with static vars keys or values ERROR

Tags: php, arrays

I have a class that contains some static public variables containing numeric values and an associative static array that matches the numeric values with strings.

However, php doesn't let me do that, it says :
Parse error : syntax error, unexpected "$TYPE_DATE" (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Here is the simplified code:

```
class myclass
{
    public static $TYPE_DATE = 0b00010010;
    public static $TYPE_INT = 0b01010001;
    private static $types = array( "DATE"=>myclass::$TYPE_DATE, "INTEGER"=>myclass::$TYPE_INT);
}
```

Thank's in advance

Comment: shouldn't there be semicolons at the end of those first two lines in the class?

Comment: yes i just forgot to put it in this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot use static vars to be a reference for other static vars.
You can do it with a const.

```
class myclass
{
    const TYPE_DATE = 0b00010010;
    const TYPE_INT = 0b01010001;
    private static $types = array( "DATE"=>self::TYPE_DATE, "INTEGER"=>self::TYPE_INT);

    public function __construct() {

        print_r(self::$types);
    }
}

$class= new myclass();
```

The Output is: Array ( [DATE] => 18 [INTEGER] => 81 )

Another way is to set `$types` via a call of an init-function:

```
class myclass
{
    private static $TYPE_DATE = 0b00010010;
    private static $TYPE_INT = 0b01010001;
    public static $types;

    public static function init() {
        self::$types = array( "DATE"=>self::$TYPE_DATE, "INTEGER"=>self::$TYPE_INT);
    }
}
myclass::init();
print_r(myclass::$types);
```

Comment: i dont know why it is like that but it works thank you !